# Does Browser mob proxy supports capturing network traffic for applications running on localhost?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, phantomjs, browsermob

I am working upon designing an automatic client side performance tracking tool. I saw browsermob proxy alongwith selenium can be used for writing such tests. But, i am wondering if :-

**Can BMP+Selenium be used for capturing network traffic for applications running on localhost and generate HAR files ?**

I have googled and discovered tools for performing these operations, like, HAR can be generated using BMP+Selenium/Firebug+NetExport/Chrome dev tools but **I am more interested if any APIs are available for these operations like [Browser Navigation Timing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html)** ?

Comment: This question is too general / broad. I suggest you ask more specific questions.

Comment: @RonKlein My question boils down to Can BMP+Selenium be used for capturing network traffic for applications running on localhost and generate HAR files ? if not, can PhantomJS be used for it ? I want to track performance while the webapp is running locally on localhost. One solution is like [Browser Navigation Timing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html).

Comment: I understand your question, but the post includes a few more questions, that make "white noise" IMO. I truly think that if you rewrite your post with one, simple question, then the motivation to answer would increase.

Comment: @RonKlein I have updated the question to meet the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using ChromeDriver and javascript you can track performance data, for example in Java:

```
ChromeDriver driver = createChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://xxx");
Object o = driver.executeScript("return window.performance.getEntries();");
```

Returns a json object containing performance data.